# Are JSON Schema strings measured in bytes or characters?

Tags: string-length, jsonschema

In my JSON schema I want to specify that a string can't be longer than a certain amount so that I am sure that the values are not too large to fit into my database. So, I can use the maxLength keyword for this.  But, is it measuring the number of characters in the string or the number of bytes?  If I have unicode strings where multiple bytes can be used for a single character this can make a very real difference for how long a string I can fit in my database.

Comment: JSON is a textual format.  It does not know or care whether you use a Unicode encoding.  However, beware of surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the schema specification, here: http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor25, it specifies that maxLength is counting characters, not bytes.

Comment: Unfortunately "character" is not well defined. It's often taken to mean code unit, but might as well mean code point (the relationship between this measurement and the former depends on the encoding), or even various formalizations of "user-perceived character".

Comment: @delnan, Well the specification says that it's characters as defined by RFC 4627. I didn't bother looking it up because the high-level distinction between character and byte was my primary concern, but it does sound like they are trying to give a solid definition for "character".

Comment: I did look at the RFC. It's the JSON RFC and as far as I could tell, it does *not* give a solid definition of "character".